# Cross origin requests are not enabled for local html file even after disabling "security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy"

Tags: firefox

I need to make cross origin request form the local html file(not bothered about securtiy, its inside a vm and used for only learning). Even after disabling **security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy** (set to false in about:config) the firefox throws warning "Cross-Origin Request Blocked:..". How to enable it.